# Convert Image to Base64 PHP

Tags: php, mamp

I am 100% sure that I have a file on that path.

[image]

I'm trying to convert my logo.png to base64

```
$imagedata = file_get_contents("/images/account/operator/logo.png");
$base64 = base64_encode($imagedata);
```

I kept getting

```
file_get_contents(/images/account/operator/logo.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Remove the leading `/` so it reads `images/account/operator/logo.png`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the absolute path. Unless there's an /images dir in your root folder on the server, `file_get_contents()` won't be able to access it. Modify your path to the image to use the correct value.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the absolute path:

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/images/account/operator/logo.png'
```